# Using 2 different scripts on the same checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, background, limit

So I'm trying to use the following script:

```
//Limit of checked checkboxes    
function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
  var checkgroup=checkgroup
  var limit=limit
  for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
    checkgroup[i].onclick=function(){
      var checkedcount=0
      for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
          checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0
      if (checkedcount>limit){
        alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" checkboxes")
        this.checked=false
      }
    }
  }
}

//change bg color if checked 
var seleccionado=new Array()
function cambia(fila){
  if(seleccionado[fila]!=true)
  {
    document.getElementById("fila"+fila).style.background='#A5FA9B';
    document.getElementById("fila"+fila).style.color='#FFFFFF';
    seleccionado[fila]=true;
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById("fila"+fila).style.background='#FFF3D6';
    document.getElementById("fila"+fila).style.color='#000000';
    seleccionado[fila]=false;
  } 
}
```

So the first function will restrict the number of checkboxes you can select and the second will change the color of the cell background once checked. The HTML would be somthing like:

```
<form id="main" name="main" method="POST">
  <font face="verdana">
    <table>
      <tr  >
        <td  id="fila1">FIRST<input name="ckb" onclick="cambia(1)" type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td  id="fila2">SECOND<input name="ckb" onclick="cambia(2)" type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td  id="fila3">THIRD<input name="ckb" onclick="cambia(3)" type="checkbox"/></td> 
    </table>
  </font>
</form>
```

And at the end a have to add the next script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  checkboxlimit(document.forms.main.ckb, 1);
</script>
```

Now, they both work perfectly alone but when I combine them only the one that restricts the number of checked boxes works. Is there a way to make them work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `checkboxlimit`, it's overwriting the click handler on those elements. What you probably want to do is call `cambia` from within your function that's checking the number of checked boxes:

```
function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
  var checkgroup=checkgroup
  var limit=limit
  for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++) {
    var fila = i + 1;
    checkgroup[i].onclick=(function(fila){
      return function () {
        var checkedcount=0
        for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
            checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0
        if (checkedcount>limit){
          alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" checkboxes")
          this.checked=false
        } else {
          cambia(fila);
        }
      }
    }(fila));
  }
}
```

That's assuming that you only want to call `cambia` provided the check is valid. Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ultranaut/HN3Db/.

Also if it wasn't already clear, you can remove the `onclick` attributes in the html since they're getting overwritten anyway.

Comment: it kinda works but it only changes de color of the second column (checking either of the 3 boxes). When I write var fila = i instead of var fila = i+1 it only changes de bg of the first...

Comment: My bad, `fila` needs to be set in an IIFE to avoid each instance passing the same parameter. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

why do you have to make two separate functions? You can call only one function and try putting an argument there.

Comment: In fact i dont need them separatly. I just used them on different proyects a while ago and thought that I could use them together on something im working now. I also try to make one script to do both things but still can get it through.